# Is it possible to add or remove jobs and triggers from running Quartz.Net job sheduler service?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

Is it possible to add or remove jobs and triggers from the running Quartz.Net sheduler service ?

Comment: When using XML config, Quartz.NET reads your config at the specified interval (quartz.plugin.xml.ScanInterval parameter). This checks for any changes. Haven't tested it, but I guess it should be possible.

Comment: without using XML can i combine Quartz.net with sql server ?

Answer (score 1):

So I have a POC (proof of concept) that is wired up to Sql Server.

I have two console apps:

```
QuartzPOC.ConsoleApp.PopulateJobs.exe
and
QuartzPOC.ConsoleApp.RunJobs.exe
```

I ran
    QuartzPOC.ConsoleApp.RunJobs.exe

with an empty (QuartzDB) database.  Obviously, no jobs ran while this was running.

While "QuartzPOC.ConsoleApp.RunJobs.exe" was running......I then ran

```
QuartzPOC.ConsoleApp.PopulateJobs.exe
```

which only puts jobs in the database.  Note : I do NOT call "IScheduler.Start" with "QuartzPOC.ConsoleApp.PopulateJobs.exe"

"QuartzPOC.ConsoleApp.PopulateJobs.exe" ends, so it is no longer running.

I waited.  (Keeping in mind that "QuartzPOC.ConsoleApp.RunJobs.exe" is still running).

Jobs started running.

The magic "call" seems to be this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP 1  TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP, NEXT_FIRE_TIME, PRIORITY FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = ''MySchedulerName'' AND TRIGGER_STATE = @state AND NEXT_FIRE_TIME <= @noLaterThan AND (MISFIRE_INSTR = -1 OR (MISFIRE_INSTR <> -1 AND NEXT_FIRE_TIME >= @noEarlierThan)) ORDER BY NEXT_FIRE_TIME ASC, PRIORITY DESC',N'@state nvarchar(7),@noLaterThan bigint,@noEarlierThan bigint',@state=N'WAITING',@noLaterThan=235333689932806505,@noEarlierThan=235333689282806505
```

So if you populate the jobs (through C# code to the Quartz.Net library)....a scheduler that is running as another process will pick up the db changes.